# Jenkins Docker Kubernetes Setup with environment variables

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I have a NodeJS service and I am creating a Jenkins pipeline for automatic deployment on GKE. It has 2 main steps - building and pushing docker image to gcr.io and authenticating with GKE and triggering pod update. Inside the docker image I want to pass securely environment variables and create .env file within the container. For that to happen I have created Secret Text credentials in jenkins and I am getting it.

getting the secret text credentials:
`CREDENTIALS_USERS_ENV = credentials('my-id')`

command passing the variable containing the secret:
`sh "docker build --build-arg ENV_FILE_CONTENT='${CREDENTIALS_USERS_ENV}' -t ${dockerTag} ."`

`ARG ENV_FILE_CONTENT RUN touch .env RUN echo "$ENV_FILE_CONTENT" >> .env`
These are the commands I have within my dockerfile. It creates the file and passes the contents, however, it stays encrypted(****) even after the image is built causing my kubernetes pods to crash not finding the environment variables within the docker container. I have searched for a solution and of course consulted chatGPT, but could not find any viable solution.

Comment: If you do this successfully, the file content will be in the Docker image in plain text, where it can be easily extracted by anyone who can pull the image.  Do you want to put this data into a Kubernetes Secret or otherwise make it available at runtime, but not "baked in" to the image?

Comment: Yeah, kubernetes secret seems to be the way to go, even though the image is private. Maybe my problem was that as you say it was pasted as plain text and the formatting is causing issues. Anyways thank you!